# How to customize the Visual Studio 2013 directory tree?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

Because I don't really like how Visual Studio 'dumps' all its files inside the root of the project directory, I'd like to use the following directory structure:

```
output\
    (configuration)    Binaries will end up in this directory. Directory is named after the current build configuration. (e.g. Debug, Release)
dependencies\
    binaries\          Binaries of dependencies end up here.
    headers\           The interfaces to the dependencies end up here.
resources\             Resource files end up here. (.rc files and images etc)
source\
    include\           Header files end up here. (.h)
    source\            Source files end up here. (.cpp)
```

Is there a way I can configure Visual Studio in such a way? I have tried to look around in the project properties, but I have no idea how that actually works. There seem to be a lot of macros and I'm not sure which to use and where to put them.

Comment: These are actually project specific settings. If you right-click a project and go to Properties, you can go to `Configuration Properties` > `General` then set the various things you want such as `Output Directory`, `Intermediate Directory`, etc. Also more settings like this are in `Configuration Properties` > `VC++ Directories`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee855621.aspx

Comment: do you mean customizing the C++ default project templates?

Comment: @Cyber he's talking about the solution explorer tree structure, not project directories.

Comment: @tenfour I want to have these changed to be on disc, physical changes. I have already said the solution explorer to mirror how files are layout on disk.

Comment: the one directory you can't control directly is the source directories. i use symbolic links for that, at the cost of some trouble with the visual studio editor, which doesn't support file identity. that said, i don't see how your structure is any better than what you get by default: it's the same impractical division into headers and implementation files, just now also physically separated, and instead of a useful division into release and debug binaries you have conflated it all into a single binaries directory.

Comment: @Cyber Thanks for the useful link. I am still confused though. Inside the VC++ Directories I can see different macros like "VC_IncludePath". Is there a place I can edit these macros? I assume I can, because most of these should be pointing to the root directory anyway. There wouldn't be any point having these macros if it weren't to edit them.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I do not want all output binaries in the 'output' directory. I want different directories inside the output directory for different configurations.

Comment: @JeroenBollen To see the macros, do the following. Go to `Configuration Properties` > `General`. Then drop down the `Output Directory` and click `<Edit...>`. In the dialog that pops up, click `Macros>>`. This should list them all, they look like `$(Keyword)` for example.

Comment: @Cyber I find myself very puzzled now. The `VC++ Directories` property page doesn't list the local configuration at all. It simply points to global directories similar to what you'd find in `/usr/include` or `/usr/lib` on a Linux machine.